# Continuous linear map

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to understand how to start with this exercise.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 3$, open and bounded and 
$$
C^{1,b}(\Omega)= \{\,f\in C^1(\Omega): \text{$f$ and all its partial  derivatives $D_if$ are bounded} \}
$$
with the norm $\,\|f\|=\|f\|_{\infty} + \sum_i \|D_if\|_\infty$.

Now let $g:\Omega \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that,
$$
x \neq y \,\,\Longrightarrow\,\, |g(x,y)| \le C\,|x-y|^2
$$ 
for some constant $C>0$, 
and 
$$
\int _{\Omega} g(.,y)\,f(y)\, dy \in C^{1,b}(\Omega)\quad \text{for all $\,f\in C^b(\Omega)$.}
$$ 
Then show that there is a constant $A$ such that 
$$
\Big|\,D_i \int_{\Omega} g(x,y) \,f(y)\, dy\,\Big|\le A\|f\|_{\infty}, 
\quad\text{for all $\,\,f \in C^b(\Omega),\, x \in \Omega$ and $i=1,...,n$.}
$$
Okay let's summarize this. What I probably need to show is that the map $V: C^b(\Omega) \rightarrow C^{1,b}(\Omega)$, $f \mapsto \int_{\Omega} g(.,y)f(y) dy$ is a continuous map(it is linear). If I have this, then this solves the excercise. What's the problem here?- The thing is, we do not know anything about the nature of $g$. Furthermore, I notice that all spaces that appear here are Banach spaces!

By the way, in this excercise is a hint given that we shall use the following theorem:

$X,Y,Z$ Banach spaces and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ linear and $J:Y \rightarrow Z$ linear, injective and continuous as well as $J \circ T$ be continuous, then $T$ is also continuous.

I do not see how this is helpful cause I do not see any injective operator that appears here.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I wonder if you can choose $J \colon C^{1,b}(\Omega) \to C^b(\Omega)$ as the natural injection map.

Comment: but in that case you would have to show that the map $J \circ T$ is continuous too, which appears to be somewhat hard.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179984/map-bounded-if-composition-is-bounded/180004) is the proof of that lemma

Comment: @Siminore Then what to take for $T$ ?

Comment: @Lipschitz Can you explain "What I probably need to show is that the map $V : C^b(\Omega) \rightarrow C^{1,b}(\Omega)$,$$ f \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} g(\cdot,y)f(y)\;dy $$ is a continuous map(it is linear). If I have this, then this solves the excercise. " How ? I don't see $D_i$ which is appearing in the last inequality we are trying to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Siminore's idea, and your comment, it seems that we need only show
 $$
\Big|\int_{\Omega} g(x,y) \,f(y)\, dy\,\Big|\le A\|f\|_{\infty}$$

But $$
\Big|\int_{\Omega} g(x,y) \,f(y)\, dy\,\Big|\le\int_{\Omega} C|x-y|^2 \,f(y)\, dy \le A\|f\|_{\infty},$$ where $A=\sup_{x\in \Omega}\int_{\Omega} C|x-y|^2 dy$.

Now the bound on g was never fully used, so let me know if there is a mistake here.

Comment: What are you trying to show here ? Because $D_i$ is not coming into picture.

Comment: @DiffeoR see Siminore's comment. We need only work in $C^b$.

Comment: What I understand you are showing the boundedness of the operator $V$  defined by @Lipschitz in the problem. $T$ has to be $$D_i \circ V$$ or may be $$ f  + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} D_i \circ V, $$ otherwise what is the use of $J$ and $T$ because the $D_i$ is not appearing either in $T$ (which I think you have assumed as $V$) or $T \circ J$ which would be continuous again if we proved $T$ is continuous.

Please also see my question to Lipschitz in the comment to the problem, how just continuity of $V$ is sufficient to arrive at the solution of the problem ? Siminore, and Lipschitz also see.

Comment: @DiffeoR I am using inclusion, not differentiation, as my $J$. Differentiation is not injective.

Comment: I am quite sure on what you said, but my question is how does your estimate help in obtaining :

$$ \Big|\,D_i \int_{\Omega} g(x,y) \,f(y)\, dy\,\Big|\le A\|f\|_{\infty}, \quad\text{for all $\,\,f \in C^b(\Omega),\, x \in \Omega$ and $i=1,...,n$.} $$

Comment: @DiffeoR did you see the theorem at the end of the post? If we prove that the map to $C^b$ is continuous, the intermediate map to $C^{1,b}$ is also continuous and thus bounded, EVEN THOUGH the norms are different. It is an indirect proof using a difficult theorem.

Comment: How did you take care of $x = y$ ? 

$$ | g(x,y) | \leq C |x-y|^2 \mbox{ for } x \neq y $$

Did you discard it, as it is a set of measure "zero" ?? As it happens in this case the domain over which it is integrated is $\Omega - \{x\}$, but the estimate expression such that at $x = y$, the estimate is zero which is as good as discarding it.

What would you have done if it were some expression that did not vanish at $x = y$ while substituting in the integral. (we don't know the bound for the value at $g(x,x)$ for all $x \in \Omega$.   

Could you correct me if I am wrong ?